# Unable to create inetOrgPerson in LDAP structure

Tags: ldap, openldap, openbsd

I have an LDAP server running on OpenBSD 7.1 using the native `ldapd` implementation. I've created a basic DIT, and when attempting to add a user, I get:

```
# ldapadd -vv -H ldaps://hypnos.spookyinternet.com/ -f /tmp/users.ldif -D cn=admin,dc=spookyinternet,dc=com -w 'correct horse battery staple'
ldap_initialize( ldaps://hypnos.spookyinternet.com:636/??base )
add objectClass:
  inetOrgPerson
add uid:
  jessejames
adding new entry "uid=jessejames,ou=users,ou=accounts,ou=spookyinternet,dc=spookyinternet,dc=com"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
```

where `/tmp/users.ldif` is:

```
dn: uid=jessejames,ou=users,ou=accounts,ou=spookyinternet,dc=spookyinternet,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: jessejames
```

I've looked at the `inetOrgPerson` schema, and can't see what part of the class I'm violating, especially since none of the fields are a MUST:

```
objectclass ( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.2.2 NAME 'inetOrgPerson'
  SUP organizationalPerson
  STRUCTURAL
  MAY ( audio $ businessCategory $ carLicense $ departmentNumber $
    displayName $ employeeNumber $ employeeType $ givenName $
    homePhone $ homePostalAddress $ initials $ jpegPhoto $
    labeledURI $ mail $ manager $ mobile $ o $ pager $
    roomNumber $ secretary $ uid $ x500uniqueIdentifier $
    preferredLanguage $ userSMIMECertificate $ userPKCS12 ) )
```

All instances I could find online of `ldap_add: Object class violation (65)` all came with an accompanying message to indicate what the violation was, but unfortunately I haven't been able to get anything more specific from my client (from the `openldap-client` package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inetOrgPerson` objectClass *supplements* `organizationalPerson`, which supplements `person`, which in turn supplements `top`. This means, it *inherits* all the attributes that defined in those objectClasses. Some of these attributes are declared as MUST, and you need to specify them all. See [RFC2798](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798#section-3) (also look into [RFC4519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519))

For instance, it inherits from `person`: `MUST (sn $ cn)`, and from `top`: `MUST ( objectClass )`. So you need to define all of them too in your LDIF.

Also, some directories require that you specify all objectClasses up to the `top`:

```
dn: uid=jessejames,ou=users,ou=accounts,ou=spookyinternet,dc=spookyinternet,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: jessejames
cn: Jesse
sn: James
```

This LDIF should work (provided you've already added all the containers: `ou=users`, `ou=accounts`, etc.). However, this is clearly redundant and I suggest you to try with only `inetOrgPerson` class declared and see if it works like that.

---

If you're only interested in `uid` attribute and don't want to add `sn` and `cn`, you should not use the `inetOrgPerson` objectClass at all. You can take other route and use the `uidObject` *auxiliary* objectClass which only contains this `uid` attribute:

```
dn: uid=jessejames,ou=users,ou=accounts,ou=spookyinternet,dc=spookyinternet,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: uidObject
uid: jessejames
```

In this case you must specify both objectClasses in a LDIF because `uidObject` is not a structural objectClass, and the simplest structural objectClass out there is the base, `top`. And you can always add `inetOrgPerson` (or any other) with all its required attributes later.